# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError with Eclipse in Java EE environment

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jar

I am trying to use IBM's Java API which is generated by MDM Workbench.  I am running the code in a `Java EE` environment with `Eclipse`.  I am getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` for the class `MasterDataService` which `Eclipse` tells me is in `madclient.jar`.  All the solutions to the problem I have found online say I need to make sure the class is in my build path, but `madclient.jar` is listed under the `Libraries` tab in the `Java Build Path` dialog box for my web project which I thought meant it is in the build path.  How do I get the `MasterDataService` class in the build path?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you running your code? Directly in Eclipse or from a war/ear file?

Comment: The code is running on a Websphere 7.0 server in Rad 8.5 and it is called from a jsp page with Struts2 and Tiles (I hope that answers your question).  If I run the code inside of Rad with the Run->Debug As->Java Application I don't get the ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: I had to copy the madclient.jar file directly into the WEB-INF/lib.  Using the Deployment Assembly did not work for me.